# Scrapy: Follow URLs with a particular rule

Tags: url, sitemap, scrapy, rule, web-crawler

I'm new in Scrapy and i can't find in anywhere what i need to do.

I need scrape a set of URLs that are very similar, but i have no access from one to anoter. For example, i need to scrape the follows URLs:

```
www.example.com/1.html
www.example.com/2.html
(...)
www.example.com/1000.html
```

But on the first page is no link to the other pages, ie are independent.

How can i do this?
(sorry for my english)

Something like this:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
   name = 'example.com'
   allowed_domains = ['example.com']
   Start_urls = [
      'http://www.example.com/1.html',
      'http://www.example.com/2.html',
      'http://www.example.com/3.html',
   ]
```

But for more than 3 different pages

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override start_requests rather than Start_urls
For example:

```
def start_requests(self):
    base_url = 'http://www.example.com/
    for i in xrange(1, 10000):
        url = base_url + str(i) + '.html'
        yield Request(url, dont_filter=False, callback='parse_method')
```

Moreover, you can supply your URL list from a queue:

```
def start_requests(self):
    while True:
        url = queue.get()
        yield Request(url, dont_filter=False, callback='parse_method')
```

Please note scrapy's scheduler might be overloaded by scheduling massive URLs concurrently, so be careful with that.

Answer (score 3):

If the pages are all of that form (www.example.com/x.html), then you could do something like this:

start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/%s.html' % page for page in xrange(1, 1000)]

Comment: Excellent. Please remember to mark this as the accepted answer and to upvote it when you reach sufficient rep. :)